# How to span lines for one column with align?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align

I have an align environment with 3 columns and 2 lines, and I would like to merge the 2lines for the last column. How can I do that? I fount how to merge columns but not lines. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
    v_1 &= u_1 + v_g \qquad     && v_1^\prime = u_1^\prime + v_g  &&  v_G = \dfrac{m_1 v_1}{m_1 + m_2} \\
    v_2 &= u_2 + v_g = 0 \qquad &&  v_2^\prime = u_2^\prime + v_g 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: If you want the last line to not be aligned with the firs line, don;t use align.

Comment: Any other package suggestion then?

Answer (score 1):

Use `alignedat` for the four items on the left and fill with the last formula.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  v_1 &= u_1 + v_g     &\qquad v_1' &= u_1' + v_g \\
  v_2 &= u_2 + v_g = 0 &\qquad v_2' &= u_2' + v_g
  \end{alignedat}
  \qquad
  v_G = \frac{m_1 v_1}{m_1 + m_2}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Typing `'` instead of `^\prime` is easier.

Comment: It works nicely , thank you.